# Passing an array from node.js to another array in an HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, node.js

```
app.post('/reserveWorkspace', function(req, res) {

        connection.query( 'SELECT DeskName FROM desks WHERE stat = ?',["Booked"], function(err,     rows){
        if(err)
        {
            throw err;
        }
        else
        {
          try
           {

              res.render('workspaces.html',{myArray: rows.DeskName});
              for(i=0;i<rows.length;i++)
              {        
                console.log(rows[i].DeskName);
              }}
          catch (e)
           {
            console.log(e);
           }
        }
});
```

I have the above node.js code, what i want to accomplish is that i want to pass all the selected rows from my DB table to the "myArray" and pass the array to another javascript array in an HTML page which is workspaces.html . i can successfully display them on the console, but i cant successfully pass them to the html page.....   Any suggestions?

HERE IS THE HTML CODE:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   function myFunction(){
      var bookedSeatss =  "<%= myArray%>";
      document.getElementById("test2").value = bookedSeatss[0];
    }
 </script>
```

Comment: The closing brackets in your server code are wrong and are definitely giving you an error.

Comment: i doubt if the bracket are wrong because console.log(rows[i].DeskName) can print out everything correctly.

myArray is were i transfare all the data from the db table to......

Comment: They're wrong in your question then...

Answer (score 0):

Try to stringify them :

```
res.render('workspaces.html',{myArray: JSON.stringify(rows.DeskName)});
```

Comment: when trying that, i get stange randomized alphabets as my output.. is the code in my HTML page correct though?

Comment: Use the callback of render to print if you have an error:
res.render('workspaces.html',{myArray: JSON.stringify(rows.DeskName)}, function( err, html){console.log( err )});

Comment: i have used the callback and apparently it passes a NULL value

Comment: html parameter looks ok? you can print that too.

Comment: the html parameter only print out the html code on the console

Comment: it does pass the value now, but it only passe the first value from the array